# Calculating expected value of $(X+Y)^2$

Tags: probability

Let be $S \sim Geom(p)$ and $X$, $Y$ such, that

$$P(X=k,Y=l|S=n)=\frac{e^{-2n}n^{k+l}}{k!l!}$$  for all  $k,l=0,1,...$.
Calculate $E(X+Y)$ and $Var(X+Y)$.

So  far  I  got:

$P(X=k|S=n) =\sum_l P(X=k,Y=l|S=n)$,  which gives me $X|S=n \sim Po(n)$.
Symetrically  we get $Y|S=n \sim Po(n)$.

Then: $$E(X+Y) = \sum_{n} E[X+Y|S=n]P(S=n) \\= \sum_{n} E[X|S=n]P(S=n) + \sum_{n} E[Y|S=n]P(S=n) \\= 2E(S)=2/p$$

When calculating variance: $var(X+Y) = E((X+Y)^2)-E(X+Y)^2$, I have problem with $E((X+Y)^2)$.

How do I calculate it? Thank you.

Comment: Just expand $(X+Y)^2$ to $X^2+2XY+Y^2$ and find the expectation of those 3 terms.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, when conditioned on $S$, $X$ and $Y$ are independent Poissons with the same parameter $S$. It's a commonly used fact that the sum of independent Poissons is also Poisson, whose parameter is just the sum of the parameters. Therefore $X+Y | S \sim Po(2S)$. Then just use the following fact
$$\mathbb{E}[(X+Y)^2] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[(X+Y)^2 | S]].$$
The inner expectation is now easy to compute, because we know the distribution of $X+Y|S$, and the outer expectation will be straightforward too.

You could also use the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance).